# SOLR 8.6 Synonyms search returning ambiguous results

Tags: solr

Using SOLR default Synonyms search I am able to search Synonyms but for few cases it is giving ambiguous results.

For example one of Synonyms of "Revenue" is "Gain"

Input Keyword for search: Revenue and Company

Irrelevant Output: Our company don't want to gain success through shortcuts.

Solr version I am using: 8.6.3

Any help is very much appreciated here.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen? How do you determine whether the usage of `gain` vs `revenue` is relevant? Do you want to only transform `revenue` to `gain` and not `gain` to `revenue`? What is your actual wish?

Comment: From your question, it is difficult to understand about the problem. Kindly rephrase or explain the example in a more clearer way

Comment: I want to search Revenue along with its synonyms, But synonyms search is returning wrong results. " Our company don't want to gain success through shortcuts." this have nothing to do with Revenue.I want to search a context based search in solr.

Comment: @MatsLindh: I want to search solr synonyms but with context, I don't want to search Gain where it doesn't mean revenue or profit.

Comment: So how do you plan to determine "where it doesn't mean revenue or profit"? You're getting into NLP land here, and not something you can solve with synonyms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing - Synonyms are "dumb" - i.e. pure replacements, but you can usually make them work good enough for most use cases. OpenNLP is an Apache project that might be useful, but I haven't used it in quite some time: http://opennlp.apache.org/

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for your suggestion. I have tried openNLP already  and will be exploring it more

Comment: There are many words in English language which have double meaning.

Security  is a prime example of such words

Security means safety and security also means shares and bonds

For example 

I searched "Security of president"
I don't want shares and bonds to be searched 
Who SOLR synonyms will handle this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SOLR Synonyms search for homonyms words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920313/solr-synonyms-search-for-homonyms-words)