# SOLR Synonyms search for homonyms words

Tags: solr

There are many words in English language which have double meaning.

Security  is a prime example of such words

Security means safety and security also means shares and bonds

For example

I searched "Security of president" But I don't want shares and bonds to be searched

Who SOLR synonyms will handle this ?

Comment: No, Solr synonyms will not handle this.

Comment: This is the same question as you asked previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844027/solr-8-6-synonyms-search-returning-ambiguous-results - you'll have to have some external functionality to make a judgement about the meaning of the word, for example through NLP features.

Comment: @HectorCorrea any SOLR API available for this?

Comment: @MatsLindh: thanks for the response but for NLP, is there any built in library which will handle this? Anything NLP or AI library. Or we need to add custom rules for this handling ?

Comment: That will depend on which technology you go with and what data sets are available for that subset of technology. You should make a set of requirements and what you need, and then evaluate available libraries and find out if they fulfill those requirements. You'll probably have to look for both a library and dataset that you can use with that library that support deducing meaning for the words and languages you're looking for.

Comment: Any suggestion for Java and C# related libraries? @MatsLindh

Comment: https://opennlp.apache.org/  - https://uima.apache.org/ - https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ - https://emorynlp.github.io/nlp4j/ - https://gate.ac.uk/family/embedded.html from some quick searching. CoreNLP at least seems promising.